# How can I use arcfour encryption over sshfs?

Tags: ssh, sshfs

A recent update to my Raspbian Raspberry Pi has made arcfour sshfs fail.

From the client:

```
$ sshfs pi:~ /tmp/alskdjflkasdf/ -o Ciphers=arcfour
read: Connection reset by peer
```

On the server at `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Oct 23 22:13:58 raspberrypi sshd[5909]: fatal: no matching cipher found: client arcfour server aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com [preauth]
```

How can I reenable arcfour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like the server does not want to allow it based onthe output of `auth.log`. I'd try adding `arcfour` back into the SSH server's `sshd_config` file. From the `sshd_config` man page:

*excerpt*

```
 Ciphers
        Specifies the ciphers allowed for protocol version 2.  Multiple 
        ciphers must be comma-separated.  The supported ciphers are 
        “3des-cbc”, “aes128-cbc”, “aes192-cbc”, “aes256-cbc”, “aes128-ctr”, 
        “aes192-ctr”, “aes256-ctr”, “aes128-gcm@openssh.com”, 
        “aes256-gcm@openssh.com”, “arcfour128”, “arcfour256”,
        “arcfour”, “blowfish-cbc”, and “cast128-cbc”.  The default is:

            aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,
            aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,
            aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,
            aes256-cbc,arcfour
```

Incidentally, there is nothing wrong with your `-o Ciphers=arcfour` switches from what I can tell. I even found this SU Q&A titled: [sshfs mount without compression or encryption](https://superuser.com/questions/32884/sshfs-mount-without-compression-or-encryption) that shows the same approach.

Comment: Exactly right. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` hadn't changed for me for ages, so I suppose some package upgrade modified the default behaviour. My manually including `arcfour`, it now works again.